# What guitar tone is this?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

What kind of guitar pedals or processors do I need to get this kinda tone?

Answer (score 2):

Reverb.

That's all that's on it.

Actually, after comments, there is a single delay repeat on it too - so quiet I didn't spot it to start with.

The rest is just a very simple clean Strat sound, front pickup.
It doesn't hurt at all that he plays it well.

I was trying to find some earlier refs for a historically similar sound, but basically it's a brighter, modern version of a classic strat sound.

Hendrix is similar, but slightly dirtier - YouTube keep taking down the good mixes of this, so this is the best I could find [he's playing the wrong guitar in the video, it's definitely a strat on the record]<sup>[1]</sup>

..and I must at least bow in the direction of probably the originator of the sound. From over 60 years ago, the late Buddy Holly…

<sup>[1]</sup>If you want to hear the record at its best, then seek out the version from the Cornerstones album, which was remastered beautifully in the late 90s.

Comment: It sounds more like a delay pedal than reverb.  I can hear distinct repeats of phrases. You don't typically get that with reverb.

Comment: Ahhh…yup, I can hear it now you called it. In some points you can hear a clear repeat. There's definitely a long pre-delay rev on it though. tbh, it's not making a significant difference to the sound, it's about as 'plain clean strat' as it gets.

Comment: I agree, there is more than one effect.  Reverb, Delay, perhaps chorus too.  But not overdone.  It sounds nice.

Comment: Yes, I thought delay was in there too. There's also a lot of pad in the background, which makes it difficult to determine exactly what's happening in parts.

Answer (score 1):

Hm! lovely! that's a mixture of Dire Straits and Hank Marvin :-)

I'd go for ..

1. A reverb
2. A mild delay as well
3. Probably a compressor
4. New bright-sounding strings
5. An excellent & very clean playing technique

Comment: Hank used lots of delay (echo), and maybe no reverb. But it's still that strat single coil pup sound. Like no.5.

Comment: @Tim : Good point - in fact I think it would have been a tape delay in those early days ? They tend to have their own nuance, like the sound becoming slightly more dull in tone as a sound is echoed then "re-echoed"

Comment: He used a tape echo (various makes) into the later days, too. With several heads, there were many subtly different echoes to be made, unlike the recent '2-head' digitals. Yes, the degradation was part of the Shads sound. Not too badly re-made on a Zoom pedal I don't use much any more.